# Insert Unicode string to SQL Server using linq

Tags: linq, unicode, nvarchar

I have a table with column Name is **nvarchar**

In SQL statement i using N prefix to save data with Unicode

```
Insert into TBL_Name (Name) values(N'Hôm nay đẹp trời')
```

it's work fine.
But i don't know how to **save unicode string when using Linq**?

Please help me.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`N` prefix mean string literal will be unicode.

When you use **LinQ** on `nvarchar` field **LinQ** already knows that your string will be Unicode. So you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Thank you, i don't why now it's ok, but before that not ok.